# Google App Engine - Cannot Correctly Receive a GZIP HTML File

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gzip, urllib2, urlfetch

Python and Google App Engine Experts,

I would like to retrieve the TD Bank Mortgage Rate website located at this link:

"http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/Default.asp"

I learned Python and Google App Engine through tutorials this evening and am stuck with what I believe is perhaps a GZIP issue.

Ideally I would like someone to either fix the code that I am pasting below. Or provide the correct code (if this would be easier) to successfully receive this webpage and be able to parse it in python/google app engine.

Attempt 1 - URLFETCH

```
import webapp2
import gzip

import StringIO

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = "http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/Default.asp"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
                                                 'Accept': 'text/html',
                                                 'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en',
                                                 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                                                 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
        f = StringIO.StringIO(result.content)
        c = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
        content = c.read()
        self.response.out.write(content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Attempt 2 - URLLIB2

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import gzip
import StringIO
import urllib2
import httplib

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
        url = urllib2.Request('http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/Default.asp')
        url.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
        url.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        f = opener.open(url)
        compresseddata = f.read()
    compressedstream = StringIO.StringIO(compresseddata)
        c = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedstream)
        content = c.read()
        self.response.out.write(content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

YAML File:

```
application: fimrates
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: fimrates.app
```

In both cases my browser gets redirected to

```
http://localhost:8080/Default.asp?bhjs=1&bhqs=1
```

If I change the URL I am trying to read to another web page such as www.google.com the output prints properly.

Thank you in advance for your help, I really appreciate it.

-Todd

Comment: If gzip is the transport encoding, there's no need to ungzip it yourself - urlfetch will do that for you. As a rule, it's a good idea to look at your data and see if it resembles what you expect as a first step in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The Url you posted does a redirect in javascript. The only way to get the final page is if you would simulate a browser, which is IMO impossible on GAE.

I downloaded the html via `curl -L http://tdbank.mortgagewebcenter.com/Default.asp` and it gave me "Nonsupported browser". This means that this page checks in javascript for the type of browser.

http://tinypic.com/r/aa7tqd/6

Comment: If downloading the page with curl gave you 'nonsupported browser', clearly the check is on the server side, not the cient side.

Comment: To be precise: it uses logic on both sides - if you give it a user-agent of a normal browser, it'll serve a JS page which does client-side checking. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

In your fetch command, try adding the parameter "follow_redirects=True".